# Show div only in specific area?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

I want to show an option (div) only in that respective div without display to the other at the same time.

Ex:

```
<div id="div-<?php echo ID(); ?>">

<a id="option"></a>

</div>

<div id="div-<?php echo ID(); ?>">

<a id="option"></a>

</div>
```

When you hover on div show only relevant for the same.

No ideas :/

Comment: You cannot have duplicate ID elements in one page. Use Classes `.`

Comment: @Roko C. Buljan But that is inside a loop. :)

Comment: But than modify your loop :) And please read again your own question. If you understand it I'll upvote it.

Comment: @ Roko C. Buljan I know what I'm doing, I just need to know how to do it ^ ^

Comment: But we don't know what you want. So we either don't know what to do ° °

Comment: Do you mean like an [accordion](http://jqueryui.com/accordion/)?

Comment: @Roko C. Buljan Maybe I expressed myself badly, sorry.

What I am trying to do is a button that is displayed when 'hover', like facebook, when you will delete a post.

Sorry for my bad English.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<div class="parentDiv">
   <a class="hidden">Delete post</div>
</div>
<div class="parentDiv">
   <a class="hidden">Delete post</div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
a.hidden{
    display:none;
}
```

Than with jQuery:

```
$('.parentDiv').hover(function(){
  $(this).find('.hidden').stop().fadeToggle();
});
```

---

## Or without jQ:

```
.parentDiv .hidden{
    opacity:0;
    -webkit-transition: 0.3s;
            transition: 0.3s;
}
.parentDiv:hover .hidden{
    opacity:1;
}
```

Comment: Aha! Obvious. Thank you. :D